# Cannot read property 'active' of undefined - React API Call

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I wanted to know what I'm doing wrong.

I tried to display the data that I'm receiving from this API call and I'm encountering an error.

When I check with React DevTool, my state got the data.

Displaying `{total.ts}` is working but not with `{total.data.active}` when I try to acces data from this object.

Btw I wanted to know too, I'm receiving an object: `useState({})` is correct ?

Thanks for your futures answers and helping me, it's probably nothing difficult.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Axios from "axios";

function Total() {
  const [total, setTotal] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    Axios.get("https://covid2019-api.herokuapp.com/v2/total").then(
      (response) => {
        setTotal(response.data);
      }
    );
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <h1>Hello from Total</h1>
      <div className="global-container">
        <div className="title-container"></div>
        <div className="data-container">{total.data.active}</div>
        <div className="date-container">{total.ts}</div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default Total;
```

Comment: how response.data looks like? Try changing {total.data.active} to {total.data?.active}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is likely that total.data.active will generate a js error because total.data is undefined until you get your ajax call response. A check on this will probably fix the issue.

Here is an example of how it could be done (I used fetch instead of Axios but it's not the important part):

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [total, setTotal] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://covid2019-api.herokuapp.com/v2/total")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseBody) => {
        setTotal(responseBody);
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <h1>Hello from Total</h1>
      <div className="global-container">
        <div className="title-container"></div>
        <div className="data-container">
          {total && total.data ? total.data.active : ''}
        </div>
        <div className="date-container">{total.ts}</div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks you for your answer ! It worked with your code ! I will check this in details :)

Answer (score 0):

You should add condition while data is loading, because your api call is asynchronous

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Axios from "axios";

function Total() {
  const [total, setTotal] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    Axios.get("https://covid2019-api.herokuapp.com/v2/total").then(
      (response) => {
        setTotal(response.data);
      }
    );
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <h1>Hello from Total</h1>
      {
        total ? (
         <div className="global-container">
           <div className="title-container"></div>
           <div className="data-container">{total.data.active}</div>
           <div className="date-container">{total.ts}</div>
         </div>
        ) : (
          <div>Loading...</div>
        )
      }
    </>
  );
}

export default Total;
```

`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it's working ! I will need to study async in js.

Comment: Btw I just saw you're setting the state to null ? the object is useless ?

Comment: setting initial state to `{}` is ambigous you should avoid that

Comment: `Boolean({})` is always true